# How can I change the number of columns printed by `hexdump`?

Tags: hexdump

How can I change the number of columns printed by `hexdump` from the default 16 (to 21)?

Or where can I find the place to change **the default** format string used in `hexdump` in order to modify the number used there?

Comment: You can try this `hexdump -e '21/1 "%02x " "\n"'`

Comment: Please find an answer that also contains information about the default format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems that the default format is obtained thus:

```
hexdump -e '"%07.7_Ax\n"' -e '"%07.7_ax " 8/2 "%04x " "\n"'
```

From `man hexdump`:

```
 Implement the -x option:

       "%07.7_Ax\n"
       "%07.7_ax  " 8/2 "%04x " "\n"
```

If you want to understand `hexdump`'s format, you'll have to read the manual, but here's a short walkthrough of the previous format:

- The first part `%07.7_Ax\n` is the part that displays the last line that only contains the offset. Per the manual:

  ```
     _a[dox]     Display the input offset, cumulative across input files, of the
                 next byte to be displayed.  The appended characters d, o, and x
                 specify the display base as decimal, octal or hexadecimal
                 respectively.

     _A[dox]     Identical to the _a conversion string except that it is only
                 performed once, when all of the input data has been processed.
  ```
- For the second: we now understand the `"%07.7_ax  "` part. The `8/2` means *8 iterations and 2 bytes for the following,* namely, `"%04x "`. Finally, after these, we have a newline: `"\n"`.

I'm not really sure how you want your 21 bytes. Maybe this would do:

```
hexdump -e '"%07.7_Ax\n"' -e '"%07.7_ax " 21/1 "%02x " "\n"'
```

And you know how to get rid of the offset, if needed:

```
hexdump -e '21/1 "%02x " "\n"'
```